# What is the keyboard short-cut for "This Computer" rather than "Quick Access" in Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

What is the keyboard short-cut to display "This Computer" rather than "Quick Access" in Windows 10?

In previous versions, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> displayed "This Computer"

But now in Windows 10, that short-cut goes to a new "Quick Access"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows 10 you have to set where <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> opens to within the UI.

[image]

You can set File Explorer to open up to This PC by navigating to *View* then to *Options*.